# Explicitly opening stdout in Linux from C

Tags: c, linux, stdout, stdin

Is it possible to explicitly open `stdin`,`stdoutv` and `stderr` from our C program without using `dup()`, `dup2()` or saving the `STDOUT_FILENO` etc?

I know it will be open by default. But say we close the file streams in a program and calls `exec()`, how can I reopen it in the *exec-d* program?

Comment: If they're not open at program start, the question becomes input and output of what?

Comment: @aschepler, Sorry I didn't get your  question. If I want to accept input from keyboard in the second program (exec-d), I will have to reopen the stream to stdin which was closed in the first program right? I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: I mean, a computer could have a number of virtual consoles, a dozen xterms, several SSH connections, etc. all with their own ways of handling input and output streams. The OS and X server determine when "the keyboard" affects one of those, but that changes all the time. Also, if the parent closed its stdin in the forked child, that means it doesn't want the child to consume its input, often because it will still be processing it while the child runs. So trying to grab its characters could get weird.

Answer (score 3):

When [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) successfully opens a file, it returns the [lowest not-open file descriptor](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14).

If your child process has no open file on file descriptors 0, 1, or 2 (aka standard input, output, error), then the first `open()` will open file descriptor 0 or standard input; the second will open file descriptor 1 or standard output; the third will open file descriptor 2 or standard error.  No further tweaks are necessary.  There's no need to use `dup()` or `dup2()` — or `fcntl()` with `F_DUPFD`.  The file streams `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` expect to use file descriptors 0, 1, 2.  They will work as long as you've not used them before you open the files.

How you determine which file to open is anyone's guess.  Maybe the file names are hard coded, or the names are stored in environment variables, or there are command line arguments to guide you.

Comment: So, if I have to open a stream  'stdin' from my successor program to get input from keyboard, what parameters should I pass to the 'open()' ?

Comment: Probably you’d open `”/dev/tty”`.